# One MySql for two systems?

Tags: mysql, database, dokuwiki, question2answer

I'm building a site which contains two question2answer platforms, and one dokuwiki. They all require MySql. My webhost has a limit of two MySql databases. Can I link the same MySql db to either 2 question2answer platforms, or to one question2answer and one dokuwiki? Or will it lead to conflict?

Comment: DokuWiki doesn't need a database. You *can* use MySQL as authentication backend, see https://www.dokuwiki.org/features#easy_integration

Answer (score 1):

It appears that question2answer has a table name prefix option, as discussed [here](http://www.question2answer.org/qa/13303/how-change-qa_mysql_table_prefix-setting-config-php-file?show=13303#q13303). That would allow you to run multiple sites from the same database. I would imagine that dokuwiki has something similar.

This works by prefixing table names with a unique identifier (e.g. `mysite1_`) so that there are no name clashes between the different instances.

In your situation I would use one of the available databases for all of the q2a sites, and the other for the wiki.